# jquery animate image start at wrong spot after scroll

Tags: jquery

guys I'm using a animate which  the image fly to my cart icon position after clicking the button. Although I can let image fly to right place after scroll ,but
there's  distance between my button and start spot. here's the plugin I refer http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Simple-Shopping-Cart-Plugin-With-jQuery-Bootstrap-mycart.html

My code is below . pleaese give me some ideas .thank you

```
    var goToCartIcon = function($addTocartBtn){
              var $cartIcon = $(".my-cart-icon");
              var $image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + $addTocartBtn.data("image") + '"/>').css({"position": "fixed", "z-index": "999"});
              $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);
              var position = $cartIcon.offset();
              var w = $(window);

              $image.animate({
                top: position.top-w.scrollTop(),
                left: position.left-w.scrollLeft()
              }, 500 , "linear", function() {
                $image.remove();
              });
            }
```

Comment: There's 10 plugins on that page..did you combine all 10 of them into a super-cart?

Comment: sorry,I posted wrong website,I have update the correct url

Comment: If you can get that code to work as you have described, then post it that way. it's called a [mcve]